# Creating an array of child handles

Tags: system-verilog

In SystemVerilog, I have a base class `A` and derived class `B`, `C`, `D`. I would like to create an array of type `A` which has handles to `B`, `C`, `D`. Is there a more succinct way to do this than my ugly solution below?

```
module test; 
  A arr[3];
  B b;
  C c;
  D d;

  initial begin
    b = new();
    c = new();
    d = new();
    arr[0] = b;
    arr[1] = c;
    arr[2] = d;
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean without using the intermediate class variables, you can do

```
arr[0] = B::new();
```

This is a relatively new feature of SystemVerilog and some tools do not support this yet. To get around this, you can create a static `create` method that calls the constructor for you, which lets you create a class object in places like an argument to a function without ever having to declare an intermediate variable.

```
class B;
  static function C create;
     create = new;
  endfunction
endclass

arr[1] = C::create();

somefunction(C::create()); // C::new() would not work here
```

If you are using the UVM library, you get this for free

```
class C extends uvm_object;
`uvm_object_utils(C)
...
endclass
arr[3] = C::type_id::create();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that array assignment in a single statement.

```
  initial begin
    b = new();
    c = new();
    d = new();
    arr = '{b, c, d};
  end
```